# Xcode create bot for an existing Remote Git Repo

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite, osx-server, xcode-bots

I am running
Xcode 6 with OS X Server 4

With a Remote git repo (Backed by TFS) on a different server.

I can't seem to create a Bot in Xcode and have it point at the Remote Git Repo I have on a Team Foundation Server.
The repo works perfectly fine in Xcode, its added into accounts in Xcode Preferences.

When I add a bot, it goes to 'Verifying Credentials' and then bombs out giving a HTTP Status code 404 (-1) - its not listing the remote repo.

This used to work well this way before with Server 3.2.x and Xcode 5

Any ideas?

Thank

Comment: I got this problem too! I was accessing my repo (on GitHub) with http protocol and it always fails. So I add SSH credentials to my repo (In xCode Settings), and it's working now.

Comment: Are you trying to connect over https or ssh? Can the machine in question hit the https link, and does it get the same 404?

Comment: Its over HTTP and the machine can hit it correctly yes without issue :)

Comment: @ScottCorscadden sorry - read the above :)